# How to calculate quocient of sums of columns as one number?

Tags: awk

I have data:

```
  1           82        0.20971070
  2         7200    13659.50038631
  3         7443    15389.87972458
```

and I want to print quotient of sum of cilumn 3 and sum of column 2. How to do that?

I tried:

```
print((sum+=$3)/(sum+=$2))
```

and the result is 3 numbers - it computed according to rows. The desired result is 1,972807...

**EDIT**

Please one more question, I have a code:

```
/Curve No./ { in_f_format=1; next } 
/^[[:space:]]*$/ { in_f_format=0; next } 
{sum2+=$2; sum3+=$3} END{printf("%.6f\n",sum3/sum2)}
```

How to get a column of results for more files. I wrote

```
awk -f program.awk file??.txt
```

and I get only one result - for file01.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '{sum2+=$2; sum3+=$3} END{print sum3/sum2}' file
```

Output:

```
1.97281
```

or

```
awk '{sum2+=$2; sum3+=$3} END{printf("%.20f\n",sum3/sum2)}' file
```

Output:

```
1.97280745817249592022
```

Comment: Could I have one more question? I editted my question

Comment: I recommend that you start a new question.